# Interface Builder could not open the document launchscreen.storyboard because it does not exist

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, interface-builder

How can I fix the error mentioned above?
I've tried nearly everything but nothing works. Also the Copy Bundle Resources folder contains the file.
I've no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Please post the code, that returns an error, or exactly the message from debug output. Check typos, as you could have renamed file accidentally, and lowercased / uppercased characters could by an issue

Comment: Maybe the info.plist file is the problem? The status is deleted but I've never deleted it

Comment: Yes, can be. If you can revert the change, it could help. Please post some images or code.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and here is how I solved it:

Note: I wasn't using that file, so was not necessary for me.

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICJi4.png)

On Xcode, go to your project on 'Navigator' (the first item on your left file-tree), and then go to 'Build Phases' tag.

['Build Phases' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP2hb.png)

Once there, open 'Copy Bundle Resources' and look for an item called "LaunchScreen.storyboard" (like the file that is missing). You only have to delete that registry and everything will work fine now.

I hope this will be helpful to you :)